# Firebase phone authentication: how to enable "Android Device Verification" API

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

currently I'm facing a problem about firebase phone authentication.
Whenever I searched the problem in SO, everybody said that "Android Device Verification" API shall be enabled, but the API is not searched on GCP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the Android Device Verification service [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/androidcheck.googleapis.com).

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have enabled [Android Device Check API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/androidcheck.googleapis.com?project=decoded-flag-354211) and you have added your SHA256 to the Firebase Console.

Comment: i don't found it in console now, any idea?